# Yii2: How to add an image as a navbar menuitem

Tags: image, yii2, navbar

i'm trying without success to add an image inside a Navbar menuItem.

It works fine in the brandLabel
But doesn't work on anoter menu item
(I Want to display the logged user image near his name)

I Tryed several times but doesnt seem to make it work,
Would apreciate your help please...

The Code is this:

```
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
    <div class="wrap">
<?php

NavBar::begin([

    'brandLabel' => Html::img('@themes'.'/siteImages/Logo.jpg', ['alt'=>Yii::$app->name]), 
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-default navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);

// display Login page to guests of the site
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {

    $menuItems[] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Login'), 'url' => ['/site/login'],
                    'options' => [
                        'class' => 'navbar-right',
                    ],];
}
else
{
           // Show sales content to sales+ users
    if ( Yii::$app->user->can('useSalesContent')) 
    {
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Sales'), 
                        // 'class' => "pull-left",
                        'url' =>  Yii::$app->homeUrl,
                        'linkOptions' => ['id' => 'sales',
                                          'class' => 'navbar-left',
                        ],
                    ];


    // Show Admin content to manager+ users
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('useAdminContent')) 
    {
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Administration'), 
                        'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
                        'linkOptions' => ['id' => 'admin'],
                        'options' => [
                            'class' => 'navbar-left',
                        ],];

    }

    // display Logout to logged in users
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $menuItems[] = 
        [
            'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Logout'). ' (' . Yii::$app->user-
                                          >identity->username . ')',
            'url' => ['/site/logout'],
            'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']

            //****** This is where I want the user image to be shown ****//
        ];
    }

}

// echo navbar with selected items

echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);

NavBar::end();
?>

<div class="container">
    <?= Alert::widget() ?>
    <?= $content ?>
</div>
```

endBody() ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the user model has an attribute imageUrl it would be accessible through:

`Yii::$app->user->identity->imageUrl`

This would become something like:

If you would like to add it to the logout button:

`$menuItems[] = [ 'encode'=>false, label' => Yii::t('app', 'Logout'). ' (' . Yii::$app->user- >identity->username . ') ' . Html::img(Yii::$app->user- >identity->imageUrl), 'url' => ['/site/logout'], 'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']];` 
make sure you include  `'encode' => false,`

To add it as a separate item (for instance, to give it a different link):

`$menuItems[] = [ 'encode' => false, 'label' => Html::image(Yii::$app->user- >identity->imageUrl)];`

Edit:

Make sure you include the Html with a use statement in your view, or provide the full namespace declaration with Html class.

Comment: Thanks alot, It works fine!  (just changed to Html::img instead om Html::image

Comment: Yes I saw it too. I confused it with good old Yii syntax CHtml::image(). Please accept it as an accepted answer.